# Angularjs: How to pass data from custom directive to a compile directive's scope

Tags: angularjs

I am making tests on directives compiling other directives inside the link compilation, my problem is that i cannot figure out how to pass data into the compiled directive scope, maybe it should be through attributes or through scope but yet i am not able to achieve this goal.

I have directive `A` which takes the contents with transclusion, the content is another directive `B`, directive `A` will resolve data and clone multiple `B` directives depending on the data's length, for each data there should be a `B` directive with the data gathered from the iteration, making each `B` an unique directive inside `A` directive.

so this is the code:

HTML:

```
<body ng-app="app" ng-controller="testController">
  <grid rows="3" collection="blogs">
    <blog></blog>
  </grid>
</body>
```

Javascript:

```
var app = angular.module("app", []);

app.controller("testController", function($scope) {
  $scope.blogs = [{
    id: 1,
    title: "Blog #1",
    author: "Random user"
  }, {
    id: 2,
    title: "Blog #2",
    author: "Random user"
  }, {
    id: 3,
    title: "Blog #3",
    author: "Random user"
  }, {
    id: 4,
    title: "Blog #4",
    author: "Random user"
  }, {
    id: 5,
    title: "Blog #5",
    author: "Random user"
  }, {
    id: 6,
    title: "Blog #6",
    author: "Random user"
  }, {
    id: 7,
    title: "Blog #7",
    author: "Random user"
  }, {
    id: 8,
    title: "Blog #8",
    author: "Random user"
  }, {
    id: 9,
    title: "Blog #9",
    author: "Random user"
  }];
});

app.directive("blog", function() {
  return {
    restrict: "E",
    template: blogTemplate,
    replace: true,
    scope: {
      data: "@reference"
    },
    controller: controller
  };

  function controller($scope) {
    $scope.access = function() {
      console.log($scope);
    }
  }
});

app.directive("grid", function($compile) {
  return {
    restrict: "E",
    transclude: true,
    scope: {
      columns: "@rows",
      collection: "=?"
    },
    link: link
  };


  function link(scope, element, attr, ctrl, transclude) {
    var _columnLength;
    var _columnTrack = 0;
    var columns = [];
    _columnLength = parseInt(scope.columns);

    // Create columns from row's attribute
    for (i = 0; i < _columnLength; i++) {
      var column = angular.element(document.createElement("div"));

      column.addClass("grid-column");

      columns.push(column);
    }

    // Fill all columns with the passed collection scope
    fillColumns();

    // Render all columns in the DOM
    renderColumns(element, columns);

    function renderColumns(el, columns) {
      for (let col of columns) {
        el.append(col);
      }
    }

    function fillColumns() {
      var collection = scope.collection;

      // Compile multiple transcluded content for each collection item
      for (let data of collection) {
        transclude(scope.$new(), function(clone, innerScope) {
          // Set this property to test if the compiled directive recieves it
          innerScope.test = _columnTrack;

          $compile(clone)(innerScope);

          // Append the compiled clone into its respective column
          appendColumn(clone);
        });
      }
    }

    function appendColumn(data) {
      columns[_columnTrack].append(data);

      if (_columnTrack < (_columnLength - 1)) {
        _columnTrack++;
      } else {
        _columnTrack = 0;
      }

    }
  }

});
```

the scope i wish to create is within the grid link compilation. if a runtime example is necessary, here is the [codepen](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/bWKeew), **NOTE**: codepen has a variable for the blogs template, so you can see how it is structured

Comment: do you need grid to have isolate scope? working on a solution for that case.

Comment: @Bowofola yeah.. i guess it's ok to have an isolated scope, i just need each compiled directive to recieve a data from the grid scope

Comment: seems like you are doing a lot of unnecessary dom manipulation that could be done using things like `ng-repeat` and directive template

Comment: @charlietfl i want to simulate the grid that's shown in https://plus.google.com, each post has a different height and there is no gap space between them, if i use `ng-repeat` with these directives which can have dynamic height, there could be a space gap for each line in the grid

Comment: Have built lots of complex UI's and let angular directive templates do the rendering. Let the data model drive the view!

Comment: I agree with @charlietfl this is super complicated but im hoping you have an actual use case for it lol

Comment: @charlietfl i just want to make a grid like https://plus.google.com post list view, i haven't find any module that could do that so i am making my tests if i could do that, i have done half of it, i just need to know how to pass data to a directive using `$compile`

Comment: you can check on the inspector in https://plus.google.com how these posts are placed, but anyways that's out of this question context

Comment: I did check. i see divs and a tags

Comment: the problem is for some reason the directive is compiling twice.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need an isolate scope on the child directive so you can pass in the data. This can be done by adding an attribute before compiling. One big problem was the transclude being in the for loop, resulted in the compiled elements being recompiled by transclude and the scope being lost.

This should be done once, just so the template inside of the directive(grid) can be obtained. That template can then be used to clone the copies with the data attribute.

```js
var blogTemplate = `
<div class="blog-preview">
 <div class="blog-thumbnail"></div>
 
 <div class="blog-wrapper">
  <div class="blog-head">
   <h2 class="blog-title">{{data.id}}</h2>
   <p class="blog-author">{{data.author}}r</p>
   <p class="blog-date">2017-03-06</p>
  </div>
  
  <div class="blog-actions">
   
  </div>

  <div class="blog-content">
   <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit.</p>

   <button href="#" class="blog-access" ng-click="access()">access</button>
  </div>
 </div>
</div>
`;

var app = angular.module("app", []);

app.controller("testController", function($scope) {
  $scope.blogs = [
    {
      id: 1,
      title: "Blog #1",
      author: "Random user"
    },
    {
      id: 2,
      title: "Blog #2",
      author: "Random user"
    },
    {
      id: 3,
      title: "Blog #3",
      author: "Random user"
    },
    {
      id: 4,
      title: "Blog #4",
      author: "Random user"
    },
    {
      id: 5,
      title: "Blog #5",
      author: "Random user"
    },
    {
      id: 6,
      title: "Blog #6",
      author: "Random user"
    },
    {
      id: 7,
      title: "Blog #7",
      author: "Random user"
    },
    {
      id: 8,
      title: "Blog #8",
      author: "Random user"
    },
    {
      id: 9,
      title: "Blog #9",
      author: "Random user"
    }
  ];
});

app.directive("blog", function() {
  return {
    restrict: "E",
    template: blogTemplate,
    replace: false,
    scope: {
      data: "=data"
    },
    link: link
  };

  function link($scope) {
    $scope.access = function() {
      console.log($scope.data);
    };
  }
});

app.directive("grid", function($compile) {
  return {
    restrict: "E",
    transclude: true,
    scope: {
      columns: "@rows",
      collection: "=?"
    },
    link: link
  };

  function link(scope, element, attr, ctrl, transclude) {
    var _columnLength;
    var _columnTrack = 0;
    var columns = [];
    _columnLength = parseInt(scope.columns);

    // Create columns from row's attribute
    for (i = 0; i < _columnLength; i++) {
      var column = angular.element(document.createElement("div"));

      column.addClass("grid-column");

      columns.push(column);
    }

    // Fill all columns with the passed collection scope
    fillColumns();

    // Render all columns in the DOM
    renderColumns(element, columns);

    function renderColumns(el, columns) {
      for (let col of columns) {
        el.append(col);
      }
    }

    function fillColumns() {
      var collection = scope.collection;

      // Compile multiple transcluded content for each collection item
      var idx = 0;
      var template;
      
      // fetch template
      transclude(scope, function(clone, innerScope, element) {
        template = clone;
        innerScope = innerScope;
      });
      
      for (let data of collection) {
        var dataAttr = `collection[${idx++}]`;
        var item = template.clone();
        item.attr("data", dataAttr);
        
        $compile(item)(scope);

        // Append the compiled clone into its respective column
        appendColumn(item);
      }
    }

    function appendColumn(data) {
      columns[_columnTrack].append(data);

      if (_columnTrack < _columnLength - 1) {
        _columnTrack++;
      } else {
        _columnTrack = 0;
      }
    }
  }
});
```

```css
* {
  font-family: "Raleway", sans-serif;
}

body {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  justify-content: space-between;
  align-items: stretch;
  align-content: stretch;
}

grid {
  display: flex;
}

.blog-preview {
  width: 280px;
  margin: 15px 15px 60px;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}

.blog-preview > .blog-thumbnail {
  width: 100%;
  height: 190px;
  background: #181D20;
}

.blog-preview > .blog-wrapper {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}

.blog-preview > .blog-wrapper > .blog-head {
  height: 55px;
  margin: 6px 8px;
}

.blog-preview > .blog-wrapper > .blog-head > .blog-title {
  margin: 2px 0 0 0;
}

.blog-preview > .blog-wrapper > .blog-head > p {
  font-size: 10px;
  margin: 0 0 3px 0;
}

.blog-preview > .blog-wrapper > .blog-actions {
  height: 16px;
  background: rgba(24, 29, 32, 0.5);
}

.blog-preview > .blog-wrapper > .blog-content {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}

.blog-preview > .blog-wrapper > .blog-content p {
  margin: 16px 10px;
}

.blog-preview > .blog-wrapper > .blog-content > .blog-access {
  text-decoration: none;
  text-align: center;
  vertical-align: middle;
  width: 100px;
  height: 25px;
  line-height: 25px;
  margin: auto;
  color: #FFF;
  background: #3E515A;
}
```

```html
<body ng-app="app" ng-controller="testController">
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.5.0/angular.min.js"></script>
  
  <grid rows="3" collection="blogs">
    <blog></blog>
  </grid>

</body>
```

Comment: well, thank you for helping me with this issue, your method seems better than my approach on my answer, i was once thinking if i had to pass the data as attribute scope but then i thought that might not be possible because that's being compiled in a different way than angular normally does

Comment: @nosthertus yea i have a feeling the data attribute would've gotten overriden by each item. I had the solution to pass data in, what took forever was how to use the transclusion function properly, its pretty complicated. https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$compile << need to digest that still

Answer (score 0):

i have made a workaround, i don't think it's actually a good way to do this, but at least gets it the way i was looking for.. i will take this as temporary method.

so my workaround in this transclude function goes like this:

```
function fillColumns(){
    var collection = scope.collection;

    // Compile multiple transcluded content for each collection item
    for(let data of collection){
        transclude(scope.$new(), function(clone, innerScope){
            // Set this property to test if the compiled directive recieves it
            innerScope.data = data; //This is what has changed

            $compile(clone)(innerScope);

            // Append the compiled clone into its respective column
            appendColumn(clone);
        });
    }
}
```

and then access that data from the directive scope with `$scope.$parent.data`

```
function controller($scope){
    $scope.data = $scope.$parent.data;
}
```